# Openstack: Participating in localization

Tags: localization, openstack, openstack-horizon

I just joined a project in my university and that was about translating and localizing openstack into farsi(persian) language, we were working on horizon and we were told to just translate the django file and it's commands into farsi which we did by just translating and writing equivalent statements into msgstr "" lines.

After finishing the job we informed that it wasn't the right procedure and we should have done this trough transifex website and there's already a team registered for the language and we couldn't find anywhere in the website so we could submit our own translation, so here's the question,

How can we submit the job we've done regarding to this fact that the registered team's coordinators didn't respond to our requests for joining the team and they haven't had so much progress in their job according to the website's statistics whereas our job is completely done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have translated the msgstr lines in po files, you have done the right thing. Now it's just matter of importing the file to Transifex, what should not be a problem once you have joined the translation team.